# how to property parse a dataset with user-specific date format

Tags: python, date, pandas, dataframe, dataset

I have a dataset.csv file looking like this

```
time, cost,volume,valid
Fri May 19 10:00:00 PDT 2017, 9.1,3.2,True
Fri May 19 11:03:09 PDT 2017, 5.2,4.2,False
```

Could you please help parse this dataset such that datatype is : column1: date, column2:float, column3:float, column4: boolean

Thanks
CG

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with parameters `skipinitialspace` and `parse_dates`:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""time, cost,volume,valid
Fri May 19 10:00:00 PDT 2017, 9.1,3.2,True
Fri May 19 11:03:09 PDT 2017, 5.2,4.2,False"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), skipinitialspace=True, parse_dates=[0])
print (df)
                 time  cost  volume  valid
0 2017-05-19 10:00:00   9.1     3.2   True
1 2017-05-19 11:03:09   5.2     4.2  False

print (df.dtypes)
time      datetime64[ns]
cost             float64
volume           float64
valid               bool
dtype: object
```

Comment: Ok, it works nice with sample. It works also with real data?